Purpose of Green/Orange switch on old flash unit
What is the purpose of the Green/Orange/M switch on the front of the following old camera flash? And how does it affect the chart on the back?
There is no digital electronics inside and it appears to cover a hole, possibly light sensor





As a number of answers have pointed out, this flash can uses a thyristor to quench the flash tube when the sensed reflected light reaches a certain threshold. It has three modes:
M - Manual mode - the light sensor is covered, so the thyristor is never triggered. The amount of light generated by the flash is fixed. In this mode, the camera aperture (f-stop) must be set according to the distance to the subject using the table column corresponding to the film speed by the top row labelled ASA. Just ignore the color of the green and orange rows.
Orange - Automatic - Objects up to 10 m (35 ft) away. The light sensor is fully exposed. Once the reflected light reaches the equivalent exposure of manual mode from a standard (18%) grey object at 10 m, the flash is quenched. Set the camera aperture (f-stop) according to the film speed using the orange row. This can be used for objects up to 10 m away (if the object is closer, the thyristor quenches the flash tube early so it isn't overexposed).
Green - Automatic - Objects up to 6 m (20 ft) away. The light sensor is only partially exposed, so it needs more reflected light to trigger the sensor. Set the camera aperture (f-stop) according to the film speed using the green row. The green setting provides more exposure, allowing a smaller aperture (larger f-stop number) or using slower film for the same aperture, but it can only do this for closer distances (since the maximum available power is unchanged).
Thus, green mode provides more light on the subject before the flash tube is quenched (allowing the user of a slower film or lenses), but it only works over a more limited range of distances, since the high voltage supply still has the same amount of power available.
In all cases set the shutter speed to the flash sync speed. This is the fastest shutter speed where the full frame is exposed simultaneously (usually 1/60 s or 1/126 s).
Note: The film speed specification was originally developed by the American Standards Association (hence ASA), but was later adopted internationally by the International Standards Organization (hence ISO that modern users know).

Yes, if you are using the flash as fill, you can use slower shutter speed. You can't use faster shutter speed, as the full frame won't be illuminated.

That is an auto thyristor flash. The thyristor shuts the flash off after it sees a certain amount of light based upon the setting (green/orange), and the setting is essentially a power setting.
In manual mode with the thyristor disabled/blocked the full power of the flash can use the entire scale, to include the orange row. It will always use full power.
With the thyristor enabled at full aperture (orange) it can also use the full scale including the orange row. Only it may (or may not) shut the flash down before full power is used, based on the reflected light sensed.
And with the thyristor enabled with the restricted aperture (green) it can use the full scale up to/including the green line. It may also shut the flash down before all of the available power is used. Due to the restricted aperture the flash must put out more light before the thyristor receives enough light to cause it to terminate the flash. I.e. at 6m the green mode will put out two stops more light than the orange mode.

I think the switch controls the total amount of reflected light that would need to be received before the thyristor dumps any remaining energy to ground.  In the green position, it will dump as soon as the unit has received an amount of light energy comparable to the amount that would reflect back off a fairly dark object 6 meters away, given an uninterrupted charge.  In the orange, it will dump when it receives a (smaller) amount of energy comparable to what would have been reflected off an object 10 meters away.

@user107063, I see that I overlooked the green mode's restricted aperture... I'll edit my answer.

The flash has basically a light meter included and tries to automaticall adjust it's power. As there s no communication with the camera, you have to set the correct usage scenario.
Setting M
No automatic. The light sensor is blocked. Refer to the black squares in the table to find the correct manual settings for the given flash amount.
Setting Orange
It tries to automatically adjust the power in a limited fashion. Refer to the table from start to the orange row.
Setting Green
It tries to automatically adjust the power in a limited fashion. Refer to the table from the start to the green row.
Example
You want to take a headshot of a person appr 6 meters away, and you have loaded ISO 100 film into your camera:

Set the flash to green,
Set aperture f4 on your camera
Chose whichever shutterspeed you want, that is longer that your flash sync time. Usually 1/60 or /1/125 on older film cameras.

Why is the shutter speed not changing the settings? Because the flash impulse is so short, that the shutter will only affect the ambient light.
Note
You might ask, if it is automatic, why do you still have to set the camera to settings as described in the table? That is because your flash cannot read your settings, so the "program" has to be based on a given setting. More modern automatic settings like TTL always need to communicate with the camera. BTW there probably is no digital processing done, it will just be a hardwired ratio of this much light in the sensor will produce that much output power.

Thanks for the answer, But suppose the subject is 4m away, would that mean you have to use Manual setting? If so than what is the point of the automatic setting?

Is it automatic? My understanding was always that it outputs a set power. That is why you have to adjust the aperture based on the distance; at longer ranges you will need top open the aperture in order to account for light falloff, and vice versa. My understanding is most likely wrong, because the eye would in that case be unused.

@timvrhn You can see the light sensor on the front.  That usually means this is an auto-thyristor flash that cuts off the flash pulse when enough light has reflected back to that sensor.  M mode is the only one where you need to adjust for distance according to the guide number.

@davolfman any idea why there are two automatic modes, one for each of two distances? You'd think that with a meter being able to tell when enough light has been outputted, there would be no need to then further account for distance

@timvrhn: If the aperture isn't open wide enough, the flash won't be able to produce enough light to adequately illuminate distant objects.  My answer covers why one would want the two modes.

@timvrhn It's most likely to provide a choice of aperture.  This would be more for DoF/bokeh control than anything else.

I had a unit like that back in the 1980s.  If memory serves, it would always put a certain amount of energy into the main storage capacitor and then when triggered dump that energy into the flash tube.  A secondary circuit would measure the cumulative amount of light received and either use a thyrister to discharge any energy in the flash cap which hasn't yet been converted to light by the flash tube, or use a thyrister to pass the flash current and a quenching circuit to turn it off.  While discharging the cap to ground would seem (and was) wasteful compared with just "turning off" the tube, it is for various reasons easier to have devices which are non-conductive when voltage is applied remain so until triggered, than to have devices interrupt an already-flowing current.  Flashes intended for taking many 100 pictures an hour would have more complex circuitry; those intended for taking 100 pictures a year might not.
In the manual mode, the secondary dump circuit will be disabled.  In the "green" mode, it will fire when a moderate amount of energy, comparable to what would be reflected off a typical subject 6 meters away, has been received.  When shooting a typical subject, the green mode may reduce the total amount of light emitted compared to manual mode, but never increase it beyond what would be needed to light a typical subject six meters away.  In "orange" mode, less light is needed to trigger the dump circuit, comparable to what would reflect off a typical subject ten meters away.
Using orange mode would have two advantages and one disadvantage compared to green mode:

Advantage #1: It would be usable over a wider range of distances.

Advantage #2: It may be less blinding for the subject(s).

Disadvantage: It would require the use of a larger f-stop and/or faster film speed.


If one wants to use a slow film speed without making the aperture overly large, and the subject isn't too far away, green mode may be advantageous.  It's designed around the expectation that a bigger fraction of the light it produces will be reflected back, thus allowing a smaller aperture or slower film to capture an adequate amount of light.  If the subject is more than six meters away, however, the total light output the flash can produce may be inadequate to light the subject.

@user107063: My impression was that a lot of inexpensive flash units, especially in the 1980s didn't have a "main thyrister" other than the tube itself.  According to the Wiki page on IGBTs, latch-up resistant IGBTs became practical in the 1990s, and that flash unit looks older than that.

@user107063: Someone who shoots many rolls of film per hour with flash, sometimes going through a roll in under a minute, would pretty much need a flash with a thyrister-quenching circuit, but the total number of pictures I ever took with the flash for my 35mm camera was probably closer to 100 than to 500, and I doubt I was alone in that.  In any case, I don't think any of the other answers addressed the fact that the sensor cuts off the flash once a total amount of light has been received, adjusting energy rather than power, ...

...or--more importantly--the trade-offs between use of the green and orange settings and the fact that the orange setting may be better with subjects that don't like bright flashes.

@user107063: I wasn't intending to "nitpick" between power and energy, but rather to note that the sensor on the flash would have no means of knowing how much light it would need to produce until after it was already active, and would respond to the fact that it had produced enough light.

@user107063: Otherwise, I've reworked the answer to recognize the existence of units that dump excess energy and those that conserve it.  I think I would have noticed if my flash took less time to cycle after lower-energy flash, but never noticed it doing so.

The whole scale on the back is just pre-computed values for a guide number of 22 @100ASA (in metres), and the green and orange values lines have the same output (distance × aperture is roughly constant in any given column), so I don't see how there can be any relationship between the lines and the position of the switch on the other side.
IMHO the green and orange switch(*) positions are just reduced power output when the flash is used for fill-ins, possibly to indicate strong or medium backlight.
(*) assuming it is a switch and not just a slider with varying opacity in front of some measure element.

Its a slider that covers a sensor
